# Weak convergence of an hilbertian basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

In the book I used to study they said that for any hilbertian basis $(e_n)_n$ we have that $e_n$ converges weakly to the null vector.

I did not succeed to prove it except in the particularly case of $\ell_2$.

Here is the attempt I tried for any separable Hilbert space $H$ :

$$
\lVert \langle e_n, v\rangle \rVert = \lVert \langle e_n, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle v, e_i\rangle e_i \rangle \rVert = \lVert \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle v, e_i\rangle\langle e_n, e_i \rangle \rVert\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lvert \langle v, e_i\rangle\lvert\lVert\langle e_n, e_i \rangle \rVert
$$

And from there I don’t know how to pursue (if it is the good starting point).

Have you some hint to provide please ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Hint: what you can say about the convergence of the series $\sum_n |\langle e_n, v\rangle|^2$?

Comment: @rebo79 Thank you for this hint ! It is an increasing and bounded (by Cauchy-Schwarz) sequence so it converges ? Then $\lvert\langle e_n,v\rangle\rvert^{2}$ converges to $0$ and we can infer (by continuity of the square root function) the convergence of $\langle e_n, v\rangle$ to $0$ ?